# Wrap a tag around href inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the HTML code there is a 'href' , is there any posiblity to wrap an A-tag() around it? I'm new to this so please don't be too harsh :)

Note that the jquery is there to find the 'href' of a child inside the div and setting that attritbute to .summary-item-wrapper

HTML:

```
<div class="summary-item-wrapper" href="www.google.no" id="yui_3_17_2_4_1483527702805_1738"><div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').wrapInner('<div id="support"></div>');

  $('#support .sqs-block-summary-v2 .summary-item').each(function () {
    var linkto = $(this).find('.summary-title a').attr('href');
   $(this).children('.summary-item-wrapper').attr('href', linkto);   

  });
});
```

Comment: question is not clear can clarify question?

Comment: Do you want a tag inside div, or outside div?

Comment: yes question is not clear

Comment: I want <a href="www.google.no"></a> if that makes sense?

Comment: Where? As child of current div, or a should wrap that div? (becomes parent)

Comment: why has the div got a href in the first place? It's not a valid attribute for a div.

Comment: Do you want us to create new anchor tag with href www.google.no using jquery ?

Comment: You shouldn't really wrap `<div>` or any block level elements with `<a>`. What you can do is, convert it into `<span>` and move the `href` to the wrapped `<a>`.

Comment: yes @VforVendetta

Comment: .summary-item-wrapper is not a tag <a>, it is a div. and href not works on divs. Change to <a></a> and let us know

Comment: And after creating anchor tag, where have to put, shall we append, or replace href attribute of div ?

Comment: Is there any way to change the div to an "a" tag with jquery? Thanks alot for input!

Comment: I suggest going back a step and following some tutorials. Unless you're a troll. Because jQuery.

Comment: Why you created div then, create anchor tag instead ?

Comment: @MagnusHenden, it is possible - if you want to convert div to a: https://jsfiddle.net/aawnmmr1/ Not sure do you want to keep the rest of attributes, but this is the one of the ways to do it.

Comment: thanks but no thanks :)

Comment: @sinisake works like a charm, thank you :) is there any way to keep other attributes at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple divs on your page you wish to convert, and to remove divs, but to keep all attributes, you can do something like this:

```js
$( "div.summary-item-wrapper" ).each(function() {

$(this).before('<a href=http://'+$(this).attr('href') +'>A link');
$(this).prev().attr('id',$(this).attr('id'));
$(this).prev().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});

$('div.summary-item-wrapper').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary-item-wrapper" href="www.google.no" id="yui_3_17_2_4_1483527702805_1738">44444444444</div>
<div class="summary-item-wrapper" href="www.google.com" id="yui_3_17_2_4_1483527702805_33333">ttttttttttt</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done with this:

```
$('#support .sqs-block-summary-v2 .summary-item-wrapper').wrap(function () {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"></a>';
});
```

Also `href="google.no"` means go to `<currentdomain>/google.no`, in case you need the `google.no` use `href="https://google.no"`

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2s0h63f6/1/).

Please consider the comments on your question too.

Comment: If you want, you can also remove the href attributes from the divs after

Comment: Thanks alot for your time to answer, will try it in a minute! :)